# Call a smart contract method from the offchain worker

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

As the title is descriptive I would like to call a method on a Sample contract deployed to runtime evm, from the off-chain worker.

For example:

```
Contract Sample {
Public five=5;
}
```

Call Sample.five() and receive 5 from the offchain worker

Comment: consider Phala Fat Contracts

Comment: Is any other way?

Comment: If you are using ink then just use Phat Contract because the contract is executed in offchain enviroment thus giving you more functionalities. Concerning other smart contract no its not possible

Comment: I am using substrate pallets, not ink.

Comment: Okey Sorry for the earlier comments. So yes you can because offchain workers can execute any http logic